# Not all code paths return a value with output parameter in method

Tags: c#

I'm practicing building a dummy application and I'm trying to take pass in an enum as a parameter and have an integer output parameter that will be used to set a member variable (`BillsOwed`).  I have two specific questions: Why is it that `ComputeRetirementBenefitCost` tells me that my variable `must be assigned to before control leaves the current method` and why isn't `ComputeRetirementBenefitCost` accessible where I have marked in my comments?  Any and all prudent future design recommendations are welcome :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GivePromotions
{
    //Different Employees in the EmpType enum extend this class
    public abstract class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateHired { get; set; }
        public RetirementPackage.RetirementPackageType PackageType { get; set; }
        public EmpType Employeetype { get; set; }
        public int NetSalary { get; set; }

        //I'd like to set the output of ComputeRetirementBenefitCost
        //in the member below but Intellisense doesn't pick it up
        //on two lines for space, commented because it doesn't work  
        //int billsOwed = Employee.RetirementPackage
        //.ComputeRetirementBenefitCost(Employee.EmpType,out benefitCost)
        public virtual void DisplayInformation()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee information: ");
            Console.WriteLine("EmployeeId = {0} ", EmployeeId);
            Console.WriteLine("Last name  = {0} ", LastName);
            Console.WriteLine("First name = {0} ", FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine("Date hired = {0} ", DateHired);
            Console.WriteLine("Salary     = {0} ", NetSalary);
        }

        public enum EmpType
        {
            Janitor,
            President,
            Manager
        }



        //an Employee 'has-a' Retirement package
        public class RetirementPackage
        {

            public enum RetirementPackageType
            {
                Basic,
                Gold,
                Silver,
                Platinum,
                Black
            }
        //method of choice here 
        //ERROR: Output parameter 'benefitCost' must be assigned to before control
        //leaves the current method
        public void ComputeRetirementBenefitCost(Employee.EmpType e, out int benefitCost)
        {   

                switch (e)
                {
                    case Employee.EmpType.President:
                         benefitCost = 100000;
                         break;
                    case Employee.EmpType.Manager:
                         benefitCost = 5000;
                         break;
                    case Employee.EmpType.Janitor:
                         benefitCost = 1000;
                         break; 



                }


            }

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `ComputeRetirementBenefitCost` it looks like you handled all possible code flows, because `enum Employee.EmpType` has three different definitions and you covered all three all them. But this is not true. From MSDN [Enumeration Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx):

> It is possible to assign any arbitrary integer value to meetingDay. For example, this line of code does not produce an error: meetingDay = (Days) 42.

In your case I can call your method like this

```
int benefitCost = 0;
ComputeRetirementBenefitCost( (Employee.EmpType) 500, out benefitCost);
```

And in this case I will be out of your code flow, so benefitCost will not be initialized. You can change implementation like this:

```
public void ComputeRetirementBenefitCost(Employee.EmpType e, out int benefitCost)
{   

    switch (e)
    {
       case Employee.EmpType.President:
           benefitCost = 100000;
           break;
       case Employee.EmpType.Manager:
           benefitCost = 5000;
           break;
       case Employee.EmpType.Janitor:
           benefitCost = 1000;
           break; 
       default:
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("e");
    }
}
```

The second problem - it looks like you are trying to invoke `ComputeRetirementBenefitCost` as a static method, but it is not static, so just add a `static` keyword to it.

Answer (score 3):

- ERROR: Output parameter 'benefitCost' must be assigned to before control:

You have to add a "default:" to your switch or set a value outside your switch as it can be that none of your three cases is hit.

- and why isn't ComputeRetirementBenefitCost accessible

Fixing the first will fix this one.
Use crtl+shif+B to build and read the errors and warnings in the error list view. Usually they tell you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: I did fix it.  I actually didn't have to add the default part of the statement if parameter was initialized, but I know it's better practice to go ahead and add it as well